# Packaging libraries as package management using Webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Good day,

I have a legacy application, dependant on many libraries (jQuery, moment.js, underscore...). The libraries were once assembled manually and added to the repo, and are loosely coupled. My wish is to port this to a modern package manager, such as npm or yarn, to avoid manually managing a bunch of dependencies when a version update is due.

I've tried using webpack, but am somehow unable to bundle these libraries in a way the they would be globally available (I am aware that this is an anti-pattern, but I do not have the resources to rewrite the legacy code).

Is it possible to do so?

IE define a dependencies.js file with require(xx) lines, and load that as a script in the browser, making the libs available globally instead of loading each one separately from a local source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With webpack, in your entry point file you can import all librairies and add them to the global scope. Then you can call your old code in a dynamic import, so global variables will be set.

```
import $ from "jquery"
import _ from "lodash"
import moment from "moment"

window.$ = $
window._ = _
window.moment = moment

import("./yourOldCode")
```